# Cannot get pivot id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I have a pivot table which handle the following tables relationship:

- riskareas: one riskarea belongs to many riskfields
- riskfields: one riskfield has many riskarea

So:

[image]

As you can see the `riskarea_riskfield` contains an `id` in this way I can know from other tables the correct riskfield association with the riskarea, eg:

```
riskfield (2) belongs to riskarea (1), pivot id (3)
```

What I'm trying to do is get the pivot id but for some reason I'm stuck, these are my models:

```
class Riskarea extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'riskareas';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'icon',
    ];

    public function riskfields()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Riskfield::class,
            RiskareaRiskfield::class,
            'riskarea_id',
            'id',
            'id',
            'riskfield_id'
        );
    }
}

class Riskfield extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = "riskfields";
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'type',
        'icon'
    ];

    public function riskareas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Riskarea::class, 'riskarea_riskfield', 'riskarea_id', 'id');
    }

    function riskareaRiskfield()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(RiskareaRiskfield::class, 'riskfield_id');
    }
}
```

In the `Riskarea` model I've used hasManyThrough because a riskarea is like a container, eg:

```
Riskarea     | Riskfield
Cardiology   | SPO2 (1)
Cardiology   | Pressure (2)
Rheumatology | SPO2 (1)
```

So when I use:

```
$riskareas = Riskarea:all();

foreach($riskarea->riskfields as $riskfield) {
    echo $riskfield->pivot ??
}
```

I cannot access to the id of the pivot but I only have the `laravel_through_key` which is the id of the `riskarea`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Riskarea extends Model
{
        
    public function riskfields()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Riskfield::class,
            'riskarea_riskfield', 
            'riskarea_id', 'riskfield_id'
        );->withPivot()
    }
}

class Riskfield extends Model
{
        
    public function riskareas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Riskarea::class, 'riskarea_riskfield', 
                'riskfield_id', 'riskarea_id')->withPivot();
    }

  
}


$riskareas = Riskarea:all();
    
    foreach($riskarea->riskfields as $riskfield) {
        echo $riskfield->pivot->id ??
    }
```

Comment: pivot is null with your code